# How to properly set up multiprocessing in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to multiprocess a highly parallelizable problem using Python 3.6.  The problem involves a class which is passed an array at instantiation.  One of the member-functions iterates through the array and works on the data, then writing it to another list.  I have a simplified version of the problem attached to this with a traditional serial calculation; however, i am a bit lost at the multiprocessing example.  I am trying to create 2 processes, one will iterate from 0 to 4, and the other one iterating from 5 to the length of the input list (i.e. 8).  I have no idea if I am setting up the processes correctly, and in addition I am not sure how to join the threads correctly.  I am not sure if this should involve Que or daeman, and any help would be appreciated.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class Test:
    def __init__(self, array_list):
        self.array_list = array_list

    def func(self, names):
        return 'Test' + names

    def iterate(self, upper, lower):
        output = [self.func(self.array_list[i]) for i in range(lower, upper)]
        return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Serial method
    test_list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
    obj1 = Test(test_list)
    results = obj1.iterate(len(test_list), 0)
    print(results)
    # Attempt at multiprocessed method (Im lost at this point!)
    p = []
    p[0] = Process(target=obj1.iterate, args=(4, 0, ))
    p[1] = Process(target=obj1.iterate, args=(8, 5, ))
```

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: To find out whether you've set up the processes "correctly", run your code.  Trace the execution with `print` statements.  Work in stages, rather than trying to write the entire design at once.  Debugging is a *lot* easier when you're tracking only one problem at a time.  I've learned this last item from experience both ways.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example uses a Queue to transfer the data back from the processes to the main process.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

class Test:
    def __init__(self, array_list):
        self.array_list = array_list

    def func(self, names):
        return 'Test' + names

    def iterate(self, upper, lower):
        output = [self.func(self.array_list[i]) for i in range(lower, upper)]
        return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Serial method
    test_list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
    obj1 = Test(test_list)
    results = obj1.iterate(len(test_list), 0)
    print(results)

    def run_and_send_back_output(queue, func, *args):
        result = func(*args) # run the func
        queue.put(result)    # send the result back


    q = Queue()
    p1 = Process(
        target=run_and_send_back_output,
        args=(q, obj1.iterate, 4, 0)
    )
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(
        target=run_and_send_back_output,
        args=(q, obj1.iterate, 8, 4)
    )
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    results = []
    while not q.empty():
        results.extend(q.get())
    print(results)
```